# How to change the border color of a single cell using dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a dynamic table and I want to change the border color of a specific cell e.g (0,1).I cannot figure out on how will access the specific cell? Any idea?

```
protected void cmdCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //clear the table
    tbl.Controls.Clear();

    int rows = Int32.Parse(txtRows.Text);
    int cols = Int32.Parse(txtCols.Text);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        TableRow rowNew = new TableRow();

        tbl.Controls.Add(rowNew);

        tbl.Rows.AddAt(0, TableRow row);

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            //create a new tablecell object
            TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();

            cellNew.Text = "Example Cell (" + row.ToString() + "," + col.ToString() + ")";

            cellNew.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            //     cellNew.Text += col.ToString() + ")";

            if (chkBorder.Checked)
            {
                cellNew.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Inset;
                cellNew.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);
            }

            rowNew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check which at which cell you are by checking `row` and `col`. And you need to specify the `BorderStyle` also, not just the color.

```
if (row == 0 && col == 1)
{
    cellNew.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    cellNew.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
}
```